# localStorage.setItemで複数の値を保存したい

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

こんにちは！

ボタンクリックで要素内の値を複数取得し、localstorageに保存したいのですがうまくできません。
コードが長くなってしまうのでこちらにて失礼します
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xGEjLO

```js
$(function() {
  // there's the gallery and the trash
  var $gallery = $("#gallery"),
      $trash = $("#trash"),
      $items = $("#items");

  // let the gallery items be draggable
  $("li", $gallery).draggable({
    cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
    revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
    containment: "document",
    helper: "clone",
    cursor: "move"
  });

  // let the trash be droppable, accepting the gallery items
  $trash.droppable({
    accept: "#gallery > li",
    activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      deleteImage(ui.draggable);
    }
  });

  // let the gallery be droppable as well, accepting items from the trash
  $gallery.droppable({
    accept: "#trash li",
    activeClass: "custom-state-active",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      recycleImage(ui.draggable);
    }
  });

  // image deletion function
  var recycle_icon = "<a href='link/to/recycle/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Recycle this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-refresh'>Recycle image</a>";

  function deleteImage($item) {
    var obj = cloneObject($item);
    var $list = $("ul", $trash).length ?
        $("ul", $trash) :
        $("<ul class='gallery ui-helper-reset'/>").appendTo($trash);
    obj.find("a.ui-icon-trash").remove();
    obj.append(recycle_icon).appendTo($list).fadeIn(function() {
      obj
        .animate({
        width: "48px"
      })
        .find("img")
        .animate({
        height: "36px"
      });
    });
    $items.text($("li", $list).length);
  }

  // image recycle function
  var trash_icon = "<a href='link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off' title='Delete this image' class='ui-icon ui-icon-trash'>Delete image</a>";

  function recycleImage($item) {

    $item.fadeOut(function() {
      $item.remove();
      $items.text($("li", $("ul", $trash)).length);
    });
  }

  // image preview function, demonstrating the ui.dialog used as a modal window
  function viewLargerImage($link) {
    var src = $link.attr("href"),
      title = $link.siblings("img").attr("alt"),
      $modal = $("img[src$='" + src + "']");

    if ($modal.length) {
      $modal.dialog("open");
    } else {
      var img = $("<img alt='" + title + "' width='384' height='288' style='display: none; padding: 8px;' />")
        .attr("src", src).appendTo("body");
      setTimeout(function() {
        img.dialog({
          title: title,
          width: 400,
          modal: true
        });
      }, 1);
    }
  }

  function cloneObject($item) {
    var obj = $item.clone();
    obj.draggable({
      cancel: "a.ui-icon",
      revert: "invalid",
      containment: "document",
      helper: "clone",
      cursor: "move"
    });
    obj.click(function(event) {
      var $item = $(this),
        $target = $(event.target);
      if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
        deleteImage($item);
      } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
        viewLargerImage($target);
      } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
        recycleImage($item);
      }

      return false;
    });

    return obj;
  }

  // resolve the icons behavior with event delegation
  $("ul.gallery > li").click(function(event) {
    var $item = $(this),
      $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-trash")) {
      deleteImage($item);
    } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-zoomin")) {
      viewLargerImage($target);
    } else if ($target.is("a.ui-icon-refresh")) {
      recycleImage($item);
    }

    return false;
  });

  //クリックに保存する
  $("button#save").click(function() {
    var items = $("li img", $("ul", $trash));


    for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
      localStorage.setItem(i, $(items[i]).attr("src"));
    }

    // 保存されたことを確認する
    for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
      $("ul#storedItems").append("<li>" +  "<img src=" + localStorage.getItem(i) + ">");
    }

  });

  $("button#clear").click(function() {
    localStorage.clear();
    $("ul#storedItems li").remove();
  });
});
```

```css
/*
Theme Name: jqueryui-com
Template: jquery
*/
a,
.title {
  color: #B24926;
}

#content a:hover {
  color: #333;
}

#banner-secondary p.intro {
  padding: 0;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#banner-secondary .download-box {
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  background: #333;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #333 0%, #444 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #333 0%, #444 100%);
  float: right;
  width: 40%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

#banner-secondary .download-box h2 {
  color: #71D1FF;
  font-size: 26px;
}

#banner-secondary .download-box .button {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#banner-secondary .download-box p {
  margin: 15px 0 5px;
}

#banner-secondary .download-option {
  width: 45%;
  float: left;
  font-size: 16px;
}

#banner-secondary .download-legacy {
  float: right;
}

#banner-secondary .download-option span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #71D1FF;
}

#content .dev-links {
  float: right;
  width: 30%;
  margin: -15px -25px .5em 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
  border-radius: 0 0 0 5px;
  box-shadow: -2px 2px 10px -2px #666;
}

#content .dev-links ul {
  margin: 0;
}

#content .dev-links li {
  padding: 0;
  margin: .25em 0 .25em 1em;
  background-image: none;
}

.demo-list {
  float: right;
  width: 25%;
}

.demo-list h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

#content .demo-list ul {
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
}

#content .demo-list li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #eee;
}

#content .demo-list .active {
  background: #fff;
}

#content .demo-list a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #3f3f3f;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px #fff;
  padding: 2% 4%;
}

.demo-frame {
  width: 70%;
  height: 350px;
}

.view-source a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.view-source > div {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: none;
}

@media all and (max-width: 600px) {
  #banner-secondary p.intro, #banner-secondary .download-box {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
  }
  #banner-secondary .download-box {
    overflow: auto;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #content .dev-links {
    width: 55%;
    margin: -15px -29px .5em 1em;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}

#gallery {
  float: left;
  width: 65%;
  min-height: 12em;
}

.gallery.custom-state-active {
  background: #eee;
}

.gallery li {
  float: left;
  width: 96px;
  padding: 0.4em;
  margin: 0 0.4em 0.4em 0;
  text-align: center;
}

.gallery li h5 {
  margin: 0 0 0.4em;
  cursor: move;
}

.gallery li a {
  float: right;
}

.gallery li a.ui-icon-zoomin {
  float: left;
}

.gallery li img {
  width: 100%;
  cursor: move;
}

#trash {
  float: right;
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 18em;
  padding: 1%;
}

#trash h4 {
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0 0 0.4em;
}

#trash h4 .ui-icon {
  float: left;
}

#trash .gallery h5 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix">
  <ul id="gallery" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix">
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header" value="3">High Tatras</h5>
      <img src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras_min.jpg" alt="The peaks of High Tatras" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header" value="2">High Tatras 2</h5>
      <img src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras2_min.jpg" alt="The chalet at the Green mountain lake" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras2.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header" value="8">High Tatras 3</h5>
      <img src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras3_min.jpg" alt="Planning the ascent" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras3.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
    <li class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">
      <h5 class="ui-widget-header value="5">High Tatras 4</h5>
      <img src="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras4_min.jpg" alt="On top of Kozi kopka" width="96" height="72">
      <a href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/droppable/images/high_tatras4.jpg" title="View larger image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">View larger</a>
      <a href="link/to/trash/script/when/we/have/js/off" title="Delete this image" class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash">Delete image</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="trash" class="ui-widget-content ui-state-default">
    <h4 class="ui-widget-header">
      Drop Items:<span id="items">0</span>
      <!-- <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span> Trash -->
    </h4>
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="save">Save</button>
  <button type="button" id="clear">Clear</button>
  <p>Stored Items</p>
  <ul id="storedItems">
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
//クリックに保存する　　のところを
$("button#save").click(function() {
  var items = $("li img", $("ul", $trash));
  for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
      localStorage.setItem(i, $(items[i]).attr("src"));
  }

  // 保存されたことを確認する
  for (var i = 0, len = localStorage.length; i < len; i++) {
    $("ul#storedItems").append("<li>" + i + "：" + localStorage.getItem(i));
  }
});
```

これだと問題なく保存されるのですが同時にタグ内のvalue値も保存させたいです
よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: *同時にタグ内のvalue値* とのことですが、これは `h5` 要素の `value` 属性の値、ということで良いのでしょうか?

Comment: はい、h5要素のvalue属性の値です。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

localStorageに1つのkeyで複数の値を保存する時は[JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)を使うと良いです。
また、取得時は[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)を使用します。

```
function set() {
  var object = {
    title: "Title",
    value: "Value"
  }
  // JSON 文字列に変換して保存
  localStorage.setItem("data", JSON.stringify(object));
}

function get() {
  // オブジェクトに戻して取得
  var object = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("data");
  object.title;
  object.value;
}
```